# GraniteDS vs BlazeDS which one is more use than the other?

Tags: java, apache-flex, blazeds, graniteds

Since i'm begining to discover this world,

I'm wondering which one of those is more use on professional developpement.

Would you be kind enough to tell me in order to make some stats ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using BlazeDS. I know that GraniteDS exists, but BlazeDS serves my needs very good. It is well documented and robust. There is also an active [Spring BlazeDS Integration project](http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex) so I have no need for an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

BlazeDS is the official software from Adobe. GraniteDS is an open-source alternative.

Feature-for-feature, you'll have to go through each one and see which features are useful for you.

Generally, BlazeDS is going to likely be better supported, but GraniteDS is likely going to have a more diverse set of features.

Answer (score 1):

From experience coding and reading blogs etc I guess the answer would be BlazeDS by a ratio of about 3:1. It's the default choice since it's official. That's doesn't mean it's better (just look at the official Adobe framework, Cairngorm, and what everyone says about that), but you didn't ask which is better.

Answer (score 0):

BlazeDS for the win.

We use it professionally and I work for a top-10 government contracting company.  Unfortunately, "using" it is different than "liking" it.

My personal opinion is that Adobe needs to do a better job of positioning itself as the defacto front-end for Java (Swing and SWT stink).  BlazeDS is too clunky for assisting with the task.  It's a beast, at times.

It's counterintuitive that BlazeDS is not considered "open source" because it's source code is open.  I look at it often in our project.  So GraniteDS is supported by more people but that's not always a good thing.